# PdfTable using iTextSharp 5.5 can find reference

Tags: c#, itext

is someone know why iam getting this error "The type or namespace name 'PdfTable' could not be found" only when i want to use PdfTable? all other code is working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , the class name is PdfPTable.

Comment: God bless you. i guess i was missing that P